# How to keep only digits without space from a price (remove symbol and comma)?

Tags: css, regex

I am looking to pick up price form this listing - https://www.flipkart.com/hp-core-i3-6th-gen-4-gb-1-tb-hdd-dos-15-be012tu-notebook/p/itmeprzhzzcrsace?pid=COMEPRZBHVZYTZHP&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&lid=LSTCOMEPRZBHVZYTZHPFHXGHP&qH=312f91285e048e09

I am using a script that uses the CSS expression ._37U4_gnOsEFLxCAC4Sn1rO to pick up the price as ₹27,490
Now, i want to put it through regex so that it removes the symbol ₹ from the price, as well as comma.

If I use [0-9] then it does removes command and ₹, but it splits the resulting price with spaces into this: 2 7 4 9 0. 
While what I want the regex to do is get me output like this: 27490

Please help!

Comment: Add a quantifier - `[0-9]+`

Comment: It gives me this result - 27 490
Can I get it without space between, or after two digits, like this 27490
?

Comment: I do not know  how the regex is used, it looks as if it just matches the input string multiple times and returns matches. There is no way to skip a part of a text within a single match. Probably, you need to replace with `[^0-9]+` regex.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var number = "₹27,490";
console.log(number.replace(/\D+/g, ""));
```